# What does it mean when Click exits with exit code 2?

Tags: python, python-click

I am currently [testing a Click CLI application](http://click.pocoo.org/5/testing/) and get `result.exit_code == 2`. Why does that happen?

Comment: Where are you getting that error? It's probably almost same as any other exit code 2.  Usually means bad input data.

Comment: What's your code, and what are the arguments you passed to the script?

Comment: [Related](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.EX_DATAERR).  From your deleted answer, it seems that you *realize* you're passing the input data incorrectly, so I'm a bit unsure of what you're asking.

Comment: I thought I figured it out and wrote the answer while I was running the tests. Still failed, even with the adjustments :-(

Comment: I had this error 2 a couple of times in other projects before and thought I'd help my future self with that question / answer.

Comment: I pass a list of strings to the function. I have no idea what is wrong there and I cannot share all of the code. Is there any way to get more information from click?

Comment: You don't have to (and shouldn't) share all of the code. You should post a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey You're funny^^ - Do you assume with 35k points I don't know this link?

Comment: Then why have you not provided one?

Comment: Because it is not that simple and not necessary for this question (as proven by my answer and the answer of Chris).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to indicate a [usage error](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/click/exceptions.py#L43):

> An internal exception that signals a usage error. This typically aborts any further handling.

This is consistent with Click's own tests, e.g.

- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/tests/test_arguments.py#L82
- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/tests/test_arguments.py#L190
- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/tests/test_arguments.py#L201
- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/tests/test_formatting.py#L157
- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/tests/test_formatting.py#L177
- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/123dd717439d8620d8d6be5574d2c9f007952326/tests/test_formatting.py#L193

Answer (score 4):

I ran

```
result = runner.invoke(cli, ['sync'])
```

instead of

```
result = runner.invoke(cli, ['--debug', 'sync'])
```

So you need to specify the flag as entered via CLI, not only pass the parameters consumed by the function if you use `@click.option`.

Additionally, the I made a typo for one of the flags.

### How to debug

1. Look at the parameters you pass to `runner.invoke` (simplest: print it)
2. Execute it via CLI (e.g. `cli(['--debug', 'sync'])`)

In my case this gave me the message

```
Error: no such option: --sync  Did you mean --syncs?
```